# Problemas con el onActivityResult

Tags: android

Quiero enviar de una actividad a otra un Json. En la primera actividad, dentro del onClick de un boton tengo lo siguiente:

```
Intent i = new Intent(PrimeraActivity.this, SegundaActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);
```

En la segunda activity, uso un metodo para devolver los datos si insertan las credenciales correctas:

```
public void iniciarActivity() {
    String pass = mPasswordView.getText().toString();
    String pass2 = Objeto.getPassword();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        if (Objects.equals(pass, pass2)) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Credenciales Correctos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            gson = new Gson();
            String myjson = gson.toJson(objeto);
            Log.i("baliza", "json:" +myjson);
            intent.putExtra("myjson", myjson);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        } else {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Credenciales inCorrectos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
}
```

En la primera activity, el metodo onActivityResult:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.i("baliza", "onActivityResult main");
    Log.i("baliza", "requestCode main: "+requestCode);
    // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_LOGIN) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data.getStringExtra("myjson") != null) {
                Log.i("baliza", "onActivityResult main if");
                gson = new Gson();
                objeto = gson.fromJson(data.getStringExtra("myjson"), ClaseObjeto.class);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

El problema es que no entra en el onActivityResult. ¿Me gustaria saber porque no pasa por ahi? ¿Y si es la manera mas correcta de hacerlo? Gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Es importante asegurar se ejecute:

```
 setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
```

de otra forma no se llamara `onActivityResult()` al regresar a tu `Activity`.

Comment: Si lo ejecuta porque he puesto un Log justo antes y otro justo despues.

Comment: Se supone que al ejecutar el finish(), vuelve a la activity anterior y debe entrar en el onActivityResult(), pero no lo hace...

Comment: Cual es el valor de REQUEST_CODE ?

Answer (score 0):

estoy convencido que tu fallo esta aqui

```
if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_LOGIN) {
```

en el  **onActivityResult**

ahi debes colocar el REQUEST_CODE que envias en el intent del  **startActivityForResult**

ya que este requestcode , es un codigo que el programardor envia al **onActivityResult** para saber que codigo debe ejecutar...cuando hay varios resultados que se envian

ya veras que si pones manualmente aqui .....

```
startActivityForResult(i, 123);
```

luego aqui le pones el mismo numero

```
 if (requestCode ==123) {
```

deberia funcionar....

Por cierto, esto lo puedes simplificar asi:

```
if ((requestCode ==123) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK)) {
```